# Firebase listener for user details update

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I need to update my user object which is stored in react context upon updating user profile so that it reflects in my other components too. I couldn't find a listener like onauthstatechanged() provided by firebase for updating firebase user data. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if there is a listener for changes to data in Firebase Authentication user profiles, there is no such thing.  You would have to periodically check the current user's profile data and check to see if anything changed since the last time you polled.  The profile data in the user object will only change when the user's token is automatically refreshed every hour, or when you call [reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#reload()) on the user object.